# Webfont performance - webfontloader vs preload

Tags: javascript, web, webfonts, google-webfonts, web-performance

I am currently thinking about using webfonts from Google, but I have still no idea which way to do it, because there are many different opinions on the internet.

I have following options:

- [Webfontloader](https://github.com/typekit/webfontloader) by typekit and google
- rel attribute [preload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Preloading_content)

When checking the performance of both on a slow 3G network, I get similar results regarding the performance. The downside of the webfontloader is the FOUT (Flash of unstyled text). Is there a way to get around that? The downside of preload is that its not supported by many browsers. Is there a fallback? I couldn't find one. Maybe you have another entirely different way.

Thanks for your help,

Nuru

Answer (score 0):

I've always found the most performant way to load webfonts is as local files on your site.  Just use .woff and .woff2 files because these will cover you back to IE8 unless there is some special reason to use an .otf font and then just have some good fallback system fonts. The problem with using external font libraries is that the only performance benefit from them is if the visitor has the same font from the same resource in their cached files from viewing said font on a different site. There are so many fonts on sites like Googlefonts and Typekit this isn't as likely as you think, and even then I've still not seen any improvement in performance. You can download the font files from Google (or of course from many other sources) and then convert them to woff and woff2 here:

https://onlinefontconverter.com/

Then load them into your site at the top of your site's CSS file. The example below is if I was using a font called geo-light and the font files are inside a `font` folder in the root of my site

```
@font-face {font-family: 'geo-light';
    src: url('fonts/geo-light.woff2') format('woff2'), url('fonts/geo-light.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal; 
}
```

You must set the font-weight and font-style to normal in the @font-face declaration and then add this again in terms of how you want the actual text styled in your elements. This will prevent rendering discrepancies across different browsers. If you download the actual different font-weights as different files you'll always need to set these to `normal`. Doing it this way will also prevent the dreaded FOUT.

```
h1, h2, h3 {
    font-family: 'geo-light', sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal; 
}
```